# Regarding a particular charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics

From this spherically symmetrical potential:

$$~~~~~~~~~~~~ V(r)= \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r}\exp(-r/a)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(q,a>0)$$

one could find the corresponding electric field:

$$\textbf{E(r)}= -\frac{\partial V(r)}{\partial r} {\bf{u_{r}}}=( \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r^{2}}+\frac{1}{a})\exp(-r/a) {\bf{u_{r}}}$$

Using Gauss's law, we can prove that the total charge $Q$ enclosed within a sphere of radius $r$ that generates the field above is given by:

$${\it{Q}} = (\frac{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}{ar^{2}}+q)\exp(-r/a)$$

Now, we can clearly see that this total positive charge decreases with the increase of the radius. What kind of distribution would give rise to this aspect of diminishing in net enclosed positive charge despite the fact that we increased the radius of the sphere that encloses these very charges?

Comment: You didn’t differentiate correctly.

Comment: You can tell this from the fact that your expression for the field is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: There are a lot of errors but this is an example of a "shielded" potential.  Your expression for the charge density if wrong.  Essentially this happens when a nucleus if shielded by an electron cloud and you want to estimate what the outer electrons "see", you have a sign error in Q and there should be a positive center with a negative cloud.

Comment: The OP didn’t try to compute the charge density; he computed the charge within radius $r$. But I agree with your point that shielding of a positive point charge by negative cloud can make the charge within $r$ a decreasing function.